# Indecomposable $\mathfrak{sl}_3$-representations

Tags: lie-algebras

**Motivation**: Consider $\mathfrak{sl}_2$. Given an integral weight $\lambda\in\mathbf Z$, then the only indecomposable modules contained in $\mathcal O_\lambda$ are the Verma modules and the simple modules with highest weight linked to $\lambda$ as well es their projective covers and injective hulls, cf. for example prop. 3.12 in [Humphreys’ category](https://books.google.de/books?id=qtoOCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA66&ots=TDV4bNQtNZ&dq=sl2%20indecomposable%20modules%20category%20o&hl=de&pg=PA67#v=onepage&q=sl2%20indecomposable%20modules%20category%20o&f=false) .

**Question**: Do similar statements hold more generally? At least for $\mathfrak{sl}_3$ or $\mathfrak{sl}_n$? I doubt, but cannot find any clear statements.

Comment: Does the paper below answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The representation types of the blocks of ${\mathscr O}$ have been completely determined [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1112/S0024609301008529/abstract).

Comment: I'm not sure how to correctly understand the paper. According to table 2, $\mathcal O_\lambda$ for ₃ has finite representation type (does this mean there are finitely many indecomposable modules?) iff ₀ = A₁, which is the case if  lies on a reflection plane. For regular , no such list exists. Is this the correct meaning of that paper?